# Why does precision_recall_curve() return similar but not equal values than confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, scikit-learn, precision-recall

**INTRO**: I wrote a very simple machine learning project which classifies numbers based on the minst dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Load
mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784", version=1)

# Prepare
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
y = y.astype(np.uint8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X.iloc[:60000], X.iloc[60000:], y.iloc[:60000], y.iloc[60000:]

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])
X_train_prepared = num_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)

# Predict
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train_prepared, y_train)
y_train_pred =  sgd_clf.predict(X_train_prepared)
```

In order to investigate the results I displayed the confusion matrix report like so:

```
print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred))
```

Which returns:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.98      0.94      0.96      5923
           1       0.98      0.95      0.96      6742
           2       0.94      0.89      0.91      5958
           3       0.93      0.85      0.89      6131
           4       0.95      0.90      0.92      5842
           5       0.91      0.82      0.86      5421
           6       0.96      0.94      0.95      5918
           7       0.96      0.91      0.93      6265
           8       0.63      0.94      0.75      5851
           9       0.92      0.85      0.88      5949

    accuracy                           0.90     60000
   macro avg       0.92      0.90      0.90     60000
weighted avg       0.92      0.90      0.91     60000
```

**GOAL**: My goal is to recalculate the precision and recall for each class and I did it by using  the `precision_recall_curve()` function, where I pick the value when the threshold is closest to 0:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx

y_score = sgd_clf.decision_function(X_train_prepared)
precision = dict()
recall = dict()
threshold = dict()
classes = sgd_clf.classes_
for i in range(0, len(classes)):
    c = classes[i]
    precision[c], recall[c], threshold[c] = precision_recall_curve(y_train==c, y_score[:, c])
    th0 = find_nearest(threshold[c], 0)+1
    print(c, round(precision[c][th0],2), round(recall[c][th0],2), threshold[c][th0])
```

However the result that I get is the following:

```
class    precision    recall    threshold
    0         0.98      0.93    0.0490132
    1         0.98      0.95    0.0270484
    2         0.94      0.86    0.1177426
    3         0.92      0.84    0.0451941
    4         0.94      0.88    0.0716969
    5         0.90      0.80    0.0486564
    6         0.96      0.91    0.0712867
    7         0.95      0.90    0.0052748
    8         0.85      0.75    0.0049975
    9         0.85      0.78    0.0060422
```

**QUESTION**: As you can see the classes are quite similar in some cases and very different in others. Would you be able to point out why this alternative way of calculating the same metric is not exactly the same offered by the `classification_report()`? Would you be able to propose a solution using the `precision_recall_curve()`?

**NOTE**: My code seems to be working correctly on other datasets for example the iris one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567206/why-does-precision-recall-curve-return-different-values-than-confusion-matrix/70568589#70568589

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/70581914/10495893

Comment: @BenReiniger I need to increase the changes to get an answer sorry.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/244433).

Comment: ok removed on stackoverflow.