# How to fully evaluate a multiclass classification problem?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, model-evaluation, multi-class, confusion-matrix

When you have a **multiclass classification problem**, what is the right way to evaluate it's performance?

What I usually do is to display the **confusion matrix** and the `classification_report()` offered by the scikit-learn python library.

However I wonder why nobody ever calculates the Precision vs. Recall and the ROC curves. Should they be calculated as well?

I found the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090541/how-to-plot-precision-and-recall-of-multiclass-classifier) which calculates them but when I try to reverse-engineer the problem to calculate for example the precision and recall of each class I do not get the same results as the ones from the `classification_report()` (as you can see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559203/why-does-precision-recall-curve-return-similar-but-not-equal-values-than-confu?noredirect=1#comment1028225_559203)).

**QUESTION**: Would you be able to provide an example to have a full analysis of the performance of a multiclass classification problem?

Answer (score 3):

Precision and recall are not straightforward to define and calculate in the multiclass situation, and I would argue that they can be badly misleading even in the two-class situation, since [every criticism against accuracy applies equally to precision and recall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352). (People do disagree with me here.)

The generalization to the ROC to multiple classes is even less clear than for precision and recall.

I would *always* use a model that gives me predicted class membership *probabilities*, not hard 0-1 classifications. There is a difference between predicted probabilities of 0.98-0.01-0.01 and 0.4-0.3-0.3, even if the most likely class is the first one in both cases.

Probabilistic predictions can be evaluated using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info). Two very common proper scoring rules that can be used in multiclass situations are [the Brier and the log score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352).