# Compare multiclass probabilities for two classifiers

Tags: classification, correlation, ranking, softmax

I have two algorithms that produce, for every observation, a vector of probabilities for 3 classes

```
           | Algo 1           | Algo 2
-------------------------------------------------
Obs 1      | [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]  | [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
Obs 2      | [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]  | [0.1, 0.1, 0.8]
Obs 3      | [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]  | [0.2, 0.4, 0.4]
....
```

I want to compare how similar the algorithms are. One simple approach is to convert the probability vectors into the winning class and evaluate a simple Accuracy, i.e. # of match / # observations.

Is there a measure or statistical test that can compare the probability vectors?

Comment: You could calculate their [KL Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

Comment: Comparison of probabilities can be adressed  via (strictly) proper scoring rules, see e.g. [this question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559320/how-to-fully-evaluate-a-multiclass-classification-problem)